# How to draw a line in javascript? What is swing/awt? Do I need to download them?

Tags: javascript, swing, awt, java-2d

I am very new to javascript, but know enough about it for what I need it for, using it for mostly web design (buttons, etc).

I've been using Adobe Brackets to edit javascript in conjunction with html/css.

My goal is to draw a line from one point to another. However, when browsing this site, I noticed people keep talking about importing "swing", "awt" and "java 2d" to draw things.

Are these plugins for a specific javascript editor? Do I need to download them?

Comment: I think you are confused about the fact Java and JavaScript are two different languages. Swing and AWT are for Java.

Comment: javascript and java are 2 different things. Swing/AWT/Java2D are only for Java, not for javascript

Comment: i think you mixed up a lot of stuff there

Comment: Swing, Awt and Java2D are Java libraries, not JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of canvas  and draw line using following code

Canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

[Full tutorial On Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)